# Click only inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a tutorial for a small website. And I want to make clickable only the tutorial bubble. So that when we try to click something apart of that bubble, nothing will happen.
In other words I want my ('html') be unclickable and ('.tutorial-bubble') - clickable.

Comment: It would be much easier to understand if you included your progress code

Comment: A tutorial needs another tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {

   $('html').on('click', function(e) {
       if($(e.target).attr('class') != 'tutorial-bubble') {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   }); 

});
```