# Make everything unclickable but one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making popup. And when it appears I want everything be unclickable but this very popup.
Here's some lousy code example:

```
<div class="content-unclickable">
   <div class="popup-clickable">some info and buttons</div>
</div>
```

Comment: add div with full width and height with 100% width and height with position absolute but set z0index less then popup. show it on popup open and hide on popup close

Comment: you have already asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32244591/click-only-inside-div

Answer (score 0):

```
$('content-unclickable *').on('mousedown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

You can return false and use to `e.preventDefault();` prevent Default behavior and `e.stopPropagation();` all items will stop propagation

Comment: this will also need to binding click again on popup close

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to display an overlay over the page that contains some elements.

Check the following example:

First, if you click on 'page element' an alert pops up.
Click on 'open popup' and you want be able to click 'page element':

```js
$('#open-popup').on('click', function() {
  $('#popup').show();
});
$('#page').on('click', function() {
  alert('you clicked on page!');
});
$('#popupElem').on('click', function() {
  alert('you clicked onside popup!');
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:100;
  display:none;
}
.popup-inner {
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
  top:50%;;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-75px;
  margin-left:-100px;
  background-color:#ececec;
  z-index:110;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="page">page element (click on me!)</span><br />
<span id="open-popup">open popup!</span>
<div id="popup">
   <div class="popup-inner">some info and buttons <b id="popupElem">click</b></div>
</div>
```